# Recommended OS for developing on Felix

Tags: linux, apache-felix

I'm looking to do some development with [Apache Felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html), and I'm curious what Linux distro I should use.  From what I can gather, it is supported on Ubuntu, is that a good place to start?  Or does it even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter really since it is all Java based anyway. Ubuntu is a good choice. You might want to install the Oracle JDK or use OpenJDK as available as package.